# Table modification

Tags: tables

I have constructed a table that needs some modification.

[image: ERRORS]

In the sixth column, I want to three values as other columns from columns(3,4,5,7,8,9). The code I use for as.

```
   \begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            &  &  \multicolumn{7}{c|}{Days of a week}\\
            \hline
            Model & Errors & M & T & W & T & F & S & S\\
            \hline
            FAR & \multirow{3}{*}{MAE} & 4.29 & 8.79 & 6.06 & \multirow{3}{*}{13} & 5.08 & 12.24 & 7.10\\
            AR & & 4.53 & 9.18 & 6.15 & & 5.50 & 12.35 & 7.19\\
            Naive & & 4.10 & 8.82 & 5.86 & & 4.59 & 10.48 & 6.25\\
            \hline
            FAR & \multirow{3}{*}{MAPE} & 4.21 & 9.81 & 5.64 & \multirow{3}{*}{14} & 5.68 & 13.38 & 7.76\\
            AR & & 4.53 & 9.18 & 6.15 & & 5.50 & 12.35 & 7.19\\
            Naive & & 3.98 & 9.95 & 5.76 & & 5.32 & 13.11 & 7.02\\
            \hline
            FAR & \multirow{3}{*}{RMSE} & 4.21 & 9.81 & 5.64 & \multirow{3}{*}{15} & 5.68 & 13.38 & 7.76\\
            AR & & 4.53 & 9.18 & 6.15 & & 5.50 & 12.35 & 7.19\\
            Naive & & 3.98 & 9.95 & 5.76 & & 5.32 & 13.11 & 7.02\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
   \end{document}
```

Please rectify as required. Second, the first two sub-columns of *Where Model* and above empty sub column and simmilary with sub-column of *Errors*.

Comment: Maybe this is a language thing, but I really do not understand, what you are trying to achieve here. Can you maybe add a sketch of how you want your table to look like?

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of "I want to three values as other columns from columns(3,4,5,7,8,9)" and "the first two sub-columns of Where Model and above empty sub column".

Comment: Thanks for your time, I simply mean that as other columns having three values except the sixth column having a single value like 13, 14,15, I want that to enter three values other than one in the said column.

Comment: My second question is that as in the first two columns where Model and Error are written having an empty space so I want to merge both to a single.

Comment: Not sure if I guessed correctly what you want, but it seems that you want remove  `\multirow{3}{*}{13}` by  `13` and then change the last `& &`  (column 6) in next row by `& 14 &`  and so on.

Comment: Thanks, Fran for your response removal of **\multirow{3}{*}** does not solve my problem

Comment: Then, please clarify your problems. A picture of the expected output, even a handmade drawing,  could help. But as far I can see, you only need to remove **all** the `\multirow` codes leaving 18 empty cells  (`&  &` = empty cell) and then write what you want in each of these 18 empty cells.

Comment: I want to enter results similar to other columns in the said column,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX!

It is not totally clear to me what you want to achieve, but if you don't want to have the cells to span over three rows in the sixth column, you just need to remove the `\multirow` command there, as was already suggested in the comments. I think, it might be good to show in an example what is meant by that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        &  &  \multicolumn{7}{c|}{Days of a week}\\
        \hline
        Model & Errors & M & T & W & T & F & S & S\\
        \hline
        FAR & \multirow{3}{*}{MAE} & 4.29 & 8.79 & 6.06 & 13 & 5.08 & 12.24 & 7.10\\
        AR & & 4.53 & 9.18 & 6.15 & 13 & 5.50 & 12.35 & 7.19\\
        Naive & & 4.10 & 8.82 & 5.86 & 13 & 4.59 & 10.48 & 6.25\\
        \hline
        FAR & \multirow{3}{*}{MAPE} & 4.21 & 9.81 & 5.64 & 14 & 5.68 & 13.38 & 7.76\\
        AR & & 4.53 & 9.18 & 6.15 & 14 & 5.50 & 12.35 & 7.19\\
        Naive & & 3.98 & 9.95 & 5.76 & 14 & 5.32 & 13.11 & 7.02\\
        \hline
        FAR & \multirow{3}{*}{RMSE} & 4.21 & 9.81 & 5.64 & 15 & 5.68 & 13.38 & 7.76\\
        AR & & 4.53 & 9.18 & 6.15 & 15 & 5.50 & 12.35 & 7.19\\
        Naive & & 3.98 & 9.95 & 5.76 & 15 & 5.32 & 13.11 & 7.02\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you want to achieve? If not, please explain in more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jasper Habicht it really works. But the only thing that remains is empty space is the first two columns to be merged with the Model and Errors.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you want the first two columns to have repeated inputs like column six, then just look how I changed the original code to achieve this repetition. You can do the same for the first two columns.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion